# Second order linear ODE with polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, fundamental-solution

I am currently stuck at solving an ODE of the form
\begin{equation}
0=\psi''(x)+(\varepsilon-(\alpha x^2-\beta)^2)\psi(x)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha,\beta$ and $\varepsilon$ are real parameters.
Anticipating $\psi\sim\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^3/3}$ for large $x$, I made the Ansatz $\psi(x) = f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^3/3}$ and obtain the ODE
\begin{equation}
0=f''(x)-2\alpha x^2 f'(x)+(\varepsilon-\beta^2+2\alpha\beta x^2-2\alpha x)f(x).
\end{equation}
Actually, I am looking for a normalized solution $\sim\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha|x|^3/3}$, where extra care needs to be taken around $x=0$. (I am a physics student and not so much concerned about mathematical rigor right now.)
But any solution would be a first step of course.
I tried a variety of things to solve the second equation:

- A powerseries approach $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$. I obtain\begin{equation}a_{n+2}=\frac{(\varepsilon-\beta^2)a_n-2\alpha(n+1)a_{n-1}+2\alpha\beta a_{n-2}}{(n+2)(n+1)}\end{equation} for $n\geq 2$, which does not look very promising.
- I also checked A. Polyanins and V.F. Zaitsevs *Handbook of Exact Solutions of Ordinary Differential Equations* but failed to transform the above ODEs into one given in the book. *Wolfram Mathematica* was not helpful either.
- I transformed the equation into an system of first order linear ODEs with $g=f'$. However such an approach is only helpful for constant coefficients, right?

I am thankful for any ideas or hints. A particular solution would be very helpful of course, as it would allow me to reduce the order of the ODE and find all solutions.
Note that, while $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given, I expect constraints on $\varepsilon$ for (normalized) solutions to exist, i.e. I would also appreciate a solution for special values of $\varepsilon$, e.g. $\varepsilon=\beta^2$.

Sorry for any grammatical errors.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect a closed form solution to exist? Also, I can't see why the power series approach you took 'does not look very promising'. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: No, there might be no closed form solution, but I thought the equation looks somewhat standard. Well, the power series approach might be helpful, but I thought the recursion relation is too complicated... Do you think I should try to investigate it further?

Comment: Well, in my opinion, that isn't a complicated recursion. Unless someone comes up with a clever transformation or finds the result in a book somewhere, I would say the power series is your best choice. You could also compute the solution numerically and see if you can glean any information from it. +1 for the good question by the way.

Comment: If you consider $ε$ as small against the other term, then the WKB approximation gives basis solutions $(αx^2−β)^{-\frac12}\exp(\pm(\frac13αx^3−βx))$ for large $x$, which in the main is $\exp(\pm\frac13αx^3)/x$.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for the quick reply. I will check both suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\psi''(x)+(\varepsilon-(\alpha x^2-\beta)^2)\psi(x)=0$

$\psi''(x)-(\alpha^2x^4-2\alpha\beta x^2+\beta^2-\varepsilon)\psi(x)=0$

Let $\psi(x)=e^{nx^3}u(x)$ ,

Then $\psi'(x)=e^{nx^3}u'(x)+3nx^2e^{nx^3}u(x)$

$\psi''(x)=e^{nx^3}u''(x)+3nx^2e^{nx^3}u'(x)+3nx^2e^{nx^3}u'(x)+(9n^2x^4+6nx)e^{nx^3}u(x)=e^{nx^3}u''(x)+6nx^2e^{nx^3}u'(x)+(9n^2x^4+6nx)e^{nx^3}u(x)$

$\therefore e^{nx^3}u''(x)+6nx^2e^{nx^3}u'(x)+(9n^2x^4+6nx)e^{nx^3}u(x)-(\alpha^2x^4-2\alpha\beta x^2+\beta^2-\varepsilon)e^{nx^3}u(x)=0$

$u''(x)+6nx^2u'(x)+((9n^2-\alpha^2)x^4+2\alpha\beta x^2+6nx+\varepsilon-\beta^2)u(x)=0$

Choose $9n^2-\alpha^2=0$ , i.e. $n=\dfrac{\alpha}{3}$ , the ODE becomes

$u''(x)+2\alpha x^2u'(x)+(2\alpha\beta x^2+2\alpha x+\varepsilon-\beta^2)u(x)=0$

Let $u(x)=e^{kx}v(x)$ ,

Then $u'(x)=e^{kx}v'(x)+ke^{kx}v(x)$

$u''(x)=e^{kx}v''(x)+ke^{kx}v'(x)+ke^{kx}v'(x)+k^2e^{kx}v(x)=e^{kx}v''(x)+2ke^{kx}v'(x)+k^2e^{kx}v(x)$

$\therefore e^{kx}v''(x)+2ke^{kx}v'(x)+k^2e^{kx}v(x)+2\alpha x^2(e^{kx}v'(x)+ke^{kx}v(x))+(2\alpha\beta x^2+2\alpha x+\varepsilon-\beta^2)e^{kx}v(x)=0$

$v''(x)+(2\alpha x^2+2k)v'(x)+(2\alpha(k+\beta)x^2+2\alpha x+k^2+\varepsilon-\beta^2)v(x)=0$

Choose $k=-\beta$ , the ODE becomes

$v''(x)+2(\alpha x^2-\beta)v'(x)+(2\alpha x+\varepsilon)v(x)=0$

Which relates to [Heun's Triconfluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E4).